# How will calculate date difference in days in asp

Tags: c#

I need date difference in days. I used TimeSpan to calculate difference.but it shows difference only in hours. I want to display in days into my textbox. whats wrong in my code.

My code is here:

```
protected void txtDate1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startdate = DateTime.Parse(txtDate.Text).Date;
    enddate = DateTime.Parse(txtDate1.Text).Date;
    remaindate = (enddate - startdate);
    txtdays.Text = remaindate.TotalDays.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What date values are you using?

Comment: startdate  and enddate are datetime.  when i get result it in hours.

Comment: Assuming you've read documentation on [TimeSpan.TotalDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays(v=vs.110).aspx) it is very what you expect from the code. Also it would be much better if you simplify your sample to hardcoded values of date instead on ones from random textboxes - it is very hard to reason what values are actually present in the textboxes.

Comment: I get textbox value in  this formate dd/MM/yyyy. So am i got any problem to convert this value ??

Answer (score 0):

here is the possible solutions:

### 1. If dates took from Textboxes :

```
DateTime d1 = TextBox1.Text!=string.Empty?Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text):DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime d2 = TextBox2.Text!=string.Empty?Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text):DateTime.MinValue;
TimeSpan tspan= d2-d1;
TextBox3.Text = tspan.TotalDays.ToString();
```

### 2. If Datetime took dynamically in code behind :

```
DateTime d1=DateTime.MinValue;
DateTime d2=DateTime.MaxValue;
TimeSpan span=d2-d1;
Console.WriteLine( "There're {0} days between {1} and {2}" , span.TotalDays, d1.ToString(), d2.ToString() );
```

Let me know, if it's helpful!

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` would be more error-proof than `Convert`, wouldn't it? `Convert` will throw an exception if the format is incorrect.